# Characterize a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{\bigcup_{i\in I'}A_i\colon I'\text{ or } (I')^c \text{ is countable}\}$ and $\mathcal{E}=\{A_i\colon i \in I\}$ where $\mathcal{E}$ is a partition of $X$. Note that $(I')^c=I\setminus I'$

Now I want to show that $\sigma(\mathcal{E})=\mathcal{A}$.

I proceed as follows:

1. Show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.
2. Show that $\mathcal{E}\subset \mathcal{A}$ since then it follows that $\sigma(\mathcal{E})\subset \mathcal{A}$
3. Lastly, show that $\mathcal{A}\subset\sigma(\mathcal{E})$

**1:**

$X\in\mathcal{A}$ since I can just pick $I=I'$.

$X\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I'}A_i=\bigcup_{j\in I\setminus I'}A_j\in\mathcal{A}$
Since for $I'$ countable, $(I\setminus I')^c$ is countable and obvious for $(I')^c$ countable.

$\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{i\in I_j}A_i = \bigcup_{i\in\bigcup_{j}I_j}A_i$ 
Now if all $I_j$ are countable, the union is too. If at least for one of the $I_j$ it holds that $(I_j)^c$ is countable, we have that $\left (\bigcup I_j\right)^c = \bigcap I_j^c$ must be countable.

We have therefore proven that $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma algebra.

**2**:

Just pick $I'=\{i\}\quad \forall i \in I$

**3**:

Here is where I am stuck at one point. If $\bigcup_{i\in I'}A_i$ with $I'$ countable, then this obviously belongs to $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$. But I cannot show that for $(I')^c$ countable..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple: if $(I')^c$ is countable, then
$$\bigcup_{i\in I'}A_i=X\, \setminus\, \bigcup_{i\in( I')^c}A_i$$
is also in $\sigma(\mathcal E)$.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Could you check if the rest of my proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, it's all correct.